# Parse `$oid` when loading JSON into mongoose document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm writing tests for my backend. I'm using `mongoose`.

To avoid writing a huge sample document from my database as a mock, I copy pasted that document into a JSON file.

Dumping the document converted the `ObjectId`s into:

```json
"_id": {
  "$oid": "6457a66965cfa04f2c2bf00f",
}
```

If I load this into a document, then my `_id` fields will just be generic Objects, instead of `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`

I also tried loading it with my model

```js
const Model = mongoose.model("MyModel", schema);
export const document = new Model(
{
 "_id": {
  "$oid": "6457a66965cfa04f2c2bf00f"
 }
});
```

but I get the same result.

How can I make `mongoose` parse the `$oid`?

Answer (score 0):

```
"_id": {
  "$oid": "6457a66965cfa04f2c2bf00f",
}
```

is **Canonical Mode** JSON format of [mongodb-extended-json](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-bsontype-ObjectId)

I guess you copy the document from cloud mongodb like below:

[image]

The copied document example:

```js
{ "_id": { "$oid": "6453682c4fd3563f4b9ccb0a" }, "username": "teresa teng", "email": "teresa.teng@example.com", "password": "123456", "notes": [{ "_id": { "$oid": "6453682c4fd3563f4b9ccb0c" }, "title": "b", "text": "b-text", "createdAt": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1683187756818" } }, "updatedAt": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1683187756818" } } }], "createdAt": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1683187756819" } }, "updatedAt": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1683188038452" } }, "__v": { "$numberInt": "1" } }
```

Now, let's delete this user document from the cloud Mongodb and recreate it using the above mongodb extended JSON. I will use [EJSON.parse(text, [options])](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson#EJSON.parse) of `bson` package to

> Parse an Extended JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by that string.

When we get the parsed js object, we can use it to create our user document.

E.g.

```
const copiedDocument = { "_id": { "$oid": "6453682c4fd3563f4b9ccb0a" }, "username": "teresa teng", "email": "teresa.teng@example.com", "password": "123456", "notes": [{ "_id": { "$oid": "6453682c4fd3563f4b9ccb0c" }, "title": "b", "text": "b-text", "createdAt": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1683187756818" } }, "updatedAt": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1683187756818" } } }], "createdAt": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1683187756819" } }, "updatedAt": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "1683188038452" } }, "__v": { "$numberInt": "1" } };
const obj = bson.EJSON.parse(JSON.stringify(copiedDocument));
console.log('obj: ', obj);
const user = new UserModel(obj)
await user.save();
```

Execution result:

```bash
obj:  {
  _id: new ObjectId("6453682c4fd3563f4b9ccb0a"),
  username: 'teresa teng',
  email: 'teresa.teng@example.com',
  password: '123456',
  notes: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("6453682c4fd3563f4b9ccb0c"),
      title: 'b',
      text: 'b-text',
      createdAt: 2023-05-04T08:09:16.818Z,
      updatedAt: 2023-05-04T08:09:16.818Z
    }
  ],
  createdAt: 2023-05-04T08:09:16.819Z,
  updatedAt: 2023-05-04T08:13:58.452Z,
  __v: 1
}
```

The user document has been recreated successfully.